# "did not have a source.properties file" when compiling Android NDK module on macOS Sonoma

Tags: android, android-ndk

Error: "did not have a source.properties file" when compiling Android NDK module.

Note: This didn't happen previously, so I suspect macOS Sonoma's way of moving/extracting files causes this.

When compiling a project that needs native (C++) sources, the aforementioned error message appeared.

If I uninstall and install the NDK via the SDK Manager in Android Studio or via `sdkmanager` command, the NDK is installed as the following directory structure:

```
ndk
└── 25.1.8937393
    ├── android-ndk-r25b
    │   ├── CHANGELOG.md
    │   ├── NOTICE
    │   ├── NOTICE.toolchain
    │   ├── README.md
    │   ├── build
    │   ├── meta
    │   ├── ndk-build
    │   ├── ndk-gdb
    │   ├── ndk-lldb
    │   ├── ndk-stack
    │   ├── ndk-which
    │   ├── prebuilt
    │   ├── python-packages
    │   ├── shader-tools
    │   ├── simpleperf
    │   ├── source.properties
    │   ├── sources
    │   ├── toolchains
    │   └── wrap.sh
    └── package.xml
```

No `source.properties` file was directly under the NDK version directory `25.1.8937393`.

Answer (score 1):

The directory `android-ndk-r25b` should not be there. The NDK version installation directory should directly contain the files, including `source.properties`.

Solution: Move the contents of `android-ndk-r25b` one level higher, and delete the empty directory `android-ndk-r25b` (Adjust `r25b` to the NDK version you are installing).

The resultant directory structure should be:

```
ndk
└── 25.1.8937393
    ├── CHANGELOG.md
    ├── NOTICE
    ├── NOTICE.toolchain
    ├── README.md
    ├── build
    ├── meta
    ├── ndk-build
    ├── ndk-gdb
    ├── ndk-lldb
    ├── ndk-stack
    ├── ndk-which
    ├── package.xml
    ├── prebuilt
    ├── python-packages
    ├── shader-tools
    ├── simpleperf
    ├── source.properties
    ├── sources
    ├── toolchains
    └── wrap.sh
```